# PHP GD Trim Transparent Pixels from created PNG

Tags: php, image, image-processing, transparency, gd

I am currently working on a website and lately have been using GD with PHP to automatically create transparent images that consist of text for use with navigation, headers, etc on the website. It saves me a lot of time in Photoshop plus I can change the text on the buttons instantly when needed.

Well I have hit a dead end here. I found the method of sizing the "textbox", created as my image, to what the size of the text is. But the problem I am facing is the fact that I am using a TTF font which is different then what GD expects the size to be. Basically, the last letter would be chopped off the outputted image. So I was wondering if there was a way to fix this while keeping a tight edge to the text or make the original textbox a much larger size and then "trim" the transparent pixels off the image.

This is the code I'm working with now...

```
<?
$text = strip_tags($_GET['btn']);
if(file_exists('nav_'.$text.'.png')) {
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    $image = imagecreatefrompng('nav_'.$text.'.png');
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
} else {
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    $fontSize = 10;
    $angle = 0;
    $font = "RonniaBold.ttf";

    $size = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $font, $text);
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(abs($size[2]) + abs($size[0]) + 5, abs($size[7]) + abs($size[1]) + 5);
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, false);

    $transparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 200, 200, 200, 127);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparentColor);

    $textColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 125, 184, 222);
    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, 1, abs($size[5])+1, $textColor, $font, str_replace('_',' ',strtoupper($text)));
    imagepng($image, 'nav_'.$text.'.png', 0);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
?>
```

Hopefully you guys have some insight to this, I could really use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever possible, I use the [Imagick class](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), as I prefer the ImageMagick library.  The following example is taken almost verbatim from the example given [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-annotation.php#94239).  It creates an image based on the size of the text supplied:

```
$text = 'Hello World!';

// Create a new ImageMagick objects.
$im = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$colour = new ImagickPixel('#000000');
$background = new ImagickPixel('none');

// Set font properties.
$draw->setFont('Fertigo_PRO.otf');
$draw->setFontSize(72);
$draw->setFillColor($colour);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

// Get font metrics.
$fm = $im->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

// Create text.
$draw->annotation(0, $fm['ascender'], $text);

// Create a new empty canvas, using the text size.
$im->newImage($fm['textWidth'], $fm['textHeight'], $background);

// Create the image.
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->drawImage($draw);

// Save the image.
$im->writeImage('test.png');
```

If you want more information on the Imagick class, I recommend the excellent [Imagick articles](http://valokuva.org/?cat=1) from [Mikko's Blog](http://valokuva.org/).

Comment: I herds that Imagick was much better for doing different things, but the problem is the fact my host does not have it installed on their servers and they cannot install it due to some kind of conflict with another plugin. That is why I am trying to do this with GD.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your code which prevents you from determining the correct size of your text - when asking for the size of the text box with imagettfbox you use $text:

```
$size = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $font, $text);
```

But when you write the text to the image you use strtoupper($text) - which makes your text bigger (unless you're using a monospaced font).